# What's the risk of corruption/data loss with constant queries

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlite, database-design

I am going to have about 4 servers (Linux) constantly (constantly as in as many as possible with multiprocessing) send queries (most of the queries with be creating new rows, however one of the servers will read data) to a data server. I imagine it would be better to have separate databases. I think sqlite3 is my best option, but I am open to recommendations. I want to minimize the risk of corruption and data loss any tips?

EDIT:
I will also have to check the database(s) to for duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really hard problem. If you want to use separate databases, you have to worry about manually keeping them consistent (which is a problem you *really* don't want to solve). Instead, have all 4 (or more generally, N) servers point to the same database instance, and let the DB do the clustering for you.  This way the DBMS can handle that concurrency and constancy stuff, and you'll still get the performance you need.

Comment: With the rate of queries, is there any risk/high risk of data loss?

Comment: No. The DBMS will refuse connections if you try to make more than it can handle. If it accepts your connection, you can be confident that your DBMS will handle the data correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach to minimising that risk is to choose a database that fully guarantees ACID compliance, and takes that guarantee seriously. Beware, because some databases systems don't always give you ACID compliance, depending on what options you have set. You'd be pretty safe with PostGres or SQL Server, for instance. MySQL - [requires a bit more thought](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html):

> In cases where you have additional software safeguards,
>   ultra-reliable hardware, or an application that can tolerate a small
>   amount of data loss or inconsistency, ***you can adjust MySQL settings to
>   trade some of the ACID reliability for greater performance or
>   throughput.***

Comment: I don't need a web database, just local. What about sqlite3? Any reason I would use PostGres over sqlite3, other than ACID compliance?

Comment: ACID compliance *is* the reason. There's no such thing as a 'web database' as such. You choose which one suits your scenario. Given that you want to minimise the chance of data loss / corruption, that would point to a fully ACID-compliant database... You could use sqlite - but given that you are using multiple servers to try and pump data into it, that doesn't sound like the best choice to me.

Comment: No worries, that's why you came here :).